# Browser close event by Process

Tags: java, javascript, process, exec

I am using a `Process` to open Internet Explorer or any other browser and then I want to go into an infinite loop until the browser is closed such that:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe");
while(true)
{
    if(p.browserclosed)
    break;
}
```

Can any one help me with this event so that I could know when the browser is closed, or there is any other method for this? In future I'm going to go to one specific JSP on the browser.

Comment: It would probably be easiest to use an API like [Selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium) or an [HttpURLConnection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/httpurlconnection) to interact *directly* with the page.

Comment: But re `Process`.  Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Comment: ok i will update it here,after going through the article

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `waitFor` method in this case.

Excerpt:

> Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this Process object has terminated.

Full reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29

Comment: if(p.waitFor==0) wont work i tried,in the refrence i couldnt find any nice way to make a comparision,can u give me a little idea about it

Comment: @siddharthgupta If you didn't get `0` , it means that the Process did'nt end successfully.

Comment: yeah of course,the user is not going to terminate the process normally,he is just going to close the browser right,is there a way to do it ?

Comment: @siddharthgupta `waitFor` "suspends" (cause it to wait) the calling thread and then notify it when the process is terminated no matter how. The exit code is an hint on how the process ends.

Comment: Thanks for the help,i got the answer to my question :) ,now i can wait,however if i could go into loop it would be nice.